# Handle Error response React.js

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, error-handling, react-redux

My Spring boot Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponseMessage> testMethod(@RequestBody MyPojo myPojo) {
        APIResponseMessage resp = new APIResponseMessage();
        try {
            serviceObj.callServiceMethod(myPojo);
            resp.setMessage("successfull!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            resp.setMessage("failed!");
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(resp);
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resp);
    }
```

React action handler class has the following method:

```
export default (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: initHandler
  });

  fetchJSON(url, 'POST', data)
    .then((json) => {
      dispatch({
        type: successHandler,
        apiResponse: json
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch({
        type: failureHandler,
        apiResponse: error,
        apiMessage : "System encountered error. Please try again later."
      })
    })
}
```

And fetchJSON is define in one of my util classes in react as :

```
export const checkStatus = response => {
  const hasError = (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300)
  if (hasError) {
    const error = new Error("This is an error") // I want to set my message that I obtained from the controller here.
    throw error
  }
  return response
}

export const parseJSON = response => response.json()

export const fetchJSON = (url, method, data) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }),
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(checkStatus).then(parseJSON);
}
```

I want to set the custom message that I get from my API to be set to the error object. I tried many options but couldn't make it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is how the Promise is being resolved, or rather, not resolved when you try to use it. Calls to 'response.json()' return a promise, during the normal flow of execution when you don't 'throw' an error, this promise is resolved, and you can work with the result.

However, when the error is thrown, you need to resolve, or '.then()' the error in the catch block.

I think this should work for you, first throw your response.text() in the checkStatus function:

```
if (hasError) {
    throw response.json()
}
```

Since you are throwing an error in a Promise, the nearest catch, or rejection callback is invoked:

```
.catch((error) => {
  dispatch({
    type: failureHandler,
    apiResponse: error,
    apiMessage : "System encountered error. Please try again later."
  })
})
```

'error' in this case is the unresolved Promise created by calling 'response.text()', so you can resolve this by wrapping the 'dispatch' in error.then() as follows:

```
.catch((error) => { // error is a Promise
    error.then((e) => {
        dispatch({
          type: failureHandler,
          apiResponse: e, // e is now the resolved value of 'response.text()'
          apiMessage : "System encountered error. Please try again later."
        });
    });
})
```

There is a simplified jsfiddle of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/LLL38vea/

Comment: My controller returns a JSON object. { message: "My Error Message" }. The problem is since the promise hasn't completed (remains in pending state) by the time I want to use this response object in the `checkStatus ` function. So I can not play around with it until the response is returned back to `fetchJSON` function.

Comment: I see what you mean, the problem is the unresolved promise, I've updated my answer above which I think should solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution. I tried a little different way but your solution will also work. I am accepting it as a solution. :)